# batch file findstr, how to?

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I'm writing a batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@REM Set defaults
SET BASE_FLDR=.\
SET BLD_TYPE=Release
@REM Check if base folder specified, if not default to current location
IF NOT [%1] == [] SET BASE_FLDR=%1
@REM Check if build type specified, if not default to Release
IF NOT [%2] == [] SET BLD_TYPE=%2
@REM Display parameters
ECHO Base folder: %BASE_FLDR%
ECHO Build type : %BLD_TYPE%
@REM Create list of subfolders to search
FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN ('DIR %BASE_FLDR% /S /B /A:D') DO (
    ECHO [%%F] | FINDSTR /E /X /IC:"%BLD_TYPE%" [%%F] >NUL && (
        ECHO %%F
    )
)
```

What I want to do is be able to call the batch file like so:

```
copydlls ./ Release
```

I want the batch file to use command line argument 1 (%1) to specify the starting location, %2 would be either "Debug" or "Release", this parsing of the arguments is fine.

In the loop I am trying to use FINDSTR to find all sub-folders that end with the folder name supplied in %2.

This bit isn't correct and is where I need help.

So far my code will capture folders correctly event where a folder contains spaces the [] fixes that, but now it doesn't match the end of string.

Comment: You are aware, that setting BLD_TYPE only works, if you are also set the BASE_FLD? If you drop the first parameter, then BLD_TYPE is empty. And why you are appending `%%F` to the Findstr parameters?

Comment: Yes, I realise that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `if %errorlevel%` try `if !errorlevel!`, because percent expansion is evaluated when a block is parsed, before it is executed.

But that wouldn't help, as your code is broken.
`Findstr /X` can't never match, because `/X` full line must match can't be true for `BLD_TYPE` only.

Btw. it could be simplyfied by moving the findstr into the FOR loop.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN ('"DIR %BASE_FLDR% /S /B /A:D | FINDSTR /E /IC:"%BLD_TYPE%" "') DO (
   echo #1 %%F
)
```

Comment: Thank you, almost, but not quite right...I don't think its handling spaces in folders correctly.

Comment: @SPlatten Then you should add at least some sample names where it fails

Comment: Anything with a space in the folder fails, looking into it I think the solution is to use FINDSTR with a regular expression, now looking for a regular expression

Comment: some progress but still not right, just changing %%F to [%%F] stops it splitting up the content but also stops the end of check from working.

Comment: @SPlatten You should edit your question, to show your REAL problems. `[%%F]` can't solve anything

Comment: maybe `FINDSTR /EIC:"\%BLD_TYPE%"` to avoid (unlikely but possible) false positives?